# how to set future time in material-ui <textfield type="datetime-local" />

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datepicker, material-ui

I want to set the default time of  to be 4 hours later to current time so if it is like 31 oct 2021 3:00 am, the default time should show 31 oct 2021 4:00 am
and for time like 31 oct 2021 10:00 pm it should show 1 nov 2021 2:00 am

I tried adding to 4 to current hour but it breaks night time.

```
const currentDate = new Date();

  const dateTime = `${currentDate.getFullYear()}-${currentDate.getMonth() + 1}-${currentDate.getDate()}T${
    currentDate.getHours() + 3
  }:${currentDate.getMinutes()}`;


<TextField
 id="datetime-local"
 type="datetime-local"
 defaultValue={`${dateTime}`}
 InputLabelProps={{
     shrink: true,
     }}
 InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: `${dateTime}` } }}
 onChange={handleChange}
 />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setHours` and `getHours` methods from Date object.

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
const fourHoursLater = new Date(
  currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() + 4)
);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-meidq?file=/demo.js)